# MegaApiClient and Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dropbox-api, mega-api

I want to implement a simple way for a user to upload a save file (a really simple json file with no personal information) to their cloud account.
The main problem is that dropbox, google drive etc... don't work with simple username and password, they need OAuth 2, and a browser for log in. But it's not easy to implement that in a Unity game, and it require that I set up a secret API key connected to my account (with limited put and get possible without pay).
I want to be able to use the final user account to upload 1 single json file to the user account, and be able to download it from another device (that's the only reason why I want to be able to log in... without log in I can use something like htput, jsonblob or myjson... but if I want the user to be able to get their save in another device I would need that they copy a really long and not easy keyurl generated by those services).

I saw that with MegaApiClient it should be possible. I imported it into Unity as a native Plugin and I was able to use it in my code.

Problem is that I cannot Login because I get [an error](https://textuploader.com/dzun2):

> TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server

the code I use it the one in the example:

```
var client = new MegaApiClient();
client.Login("username@domain.com", "passw0rd");
```

There is a way to make it work? If not do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to go with Dropbox. It's easier than I expected, but you will need to use the code flow with copy/paste (you cannot use the redirect_uri, at least I don't know how to redirect to the app on all platforms).

I don't know how to solve the mega problem.

EDIT. With Unity 2018.2 now MegaApi works.
EDIT. You can use the redirect_uri too, just redirect to 127.0.0.1 on android and localhost on pc.